# How to switch between two proofing languages?

Tags: vba, outlook

Language detection is nearly always wrong. I need VBA code that switches between English and Slovenian proofing language.

I have code that chooses English (and another one for Slovenian) as proofing language. It works.

I need to wrap an if statement around it that checks if current langId = 1060 or 1033 - and switches accordingly.

How to check the current LangId?

```
Sub SetLanguageSi()
Dim olEmail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim olInsp As Outlook.Inspector
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim oRng As Object
    On Error Resume Next
    Set olEmail = ActiveInspector.CurrentItem
        With olEmail
        Set olInsp = .GetInspector
        Set wdDoc = olInsp.WordEditor
        Set oRng = wdDoc.Range
        oRng.LanguageID = 1060 'Slovenian
        oRng.NoProofing = False
        .Display
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: so to confirm getting the Word.Range object from the Outlook.Inspector object and using an If statement to check the LanguageID property of that Range doesn't work, or yields the incorrect languageID value?

Answer (score 0):

You could use [IMultiLanguage3::DetectOutboundCodePage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/aa740773%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) (I used it quite a few times and it works great), but it is not available in VBA - only in C++, Delphi and .Net languages.